# How do I sort a generic list with a Comparer that returns inconsistent results?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort a generic list by using its member function .sort() using a custom IComparer. However, my Comparer uses external data to return a result - the objects being sorted represent three-dimensional points and during the compare I'm transforming them from world to screen coordinates and comparing the transformed ones - and so I get the error:

> Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results.

How do I go about sorting the list without getting this error?

The code of my Comparer:

```cs
public static int CompareSlices(Slice a, Slice b) {
    var cam = Game.map.Camera();
    int theta = (int)cam.rotation % Game.gameWidth;
    int orientation = 1;
    
    if (theta > 90 && theta < 270)
        orientation = -1;
    
    Vector2 aWorldCoords = a.CombinedT3().XY();
    aWorldCoords.Y = aWorldCoords.Y + orientation * (a.offset.pos.Z);
    
    Vector2 bWorldCoords = a.CombinedT3().XY();
    bWorldCoords.Y = bWorldCoords.Y + orientation * (a.offset.pos.Z);
    
    Vector2 aCameraCoords = Raylib.GetWorldToScreen2D(aWorldCoords, cam);
    Vector2 bCameraCoords = Raylib.GetWorldToScreen2D(bWorldCoords, cam);
    
    return (int)(aCameraCoords.Y + a.CombinedT3().pos.Z - bCameraCoords.Y + b.CombinedT3().pos.Z);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! If using a custom `IComparer` it would help if you post related code as you are also receiving an error. It is impossible to actually answer this as it only exist in code you've not provided. Also please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a typo in your code that is causing your problem:

```
    Vector2 aWorldCoords = a.CombinedT3().XY();
    aWorldCoords.Y = aWorldCoords.Y + orientation*(a.offset.pos.Z);
    Vector2 bWorldCoords = a.CombinedT3().XY();
    bWorldCoords.Y = bWorldCoords.Y + orientation*(a.offset.pos.Z);
```

That is `aWorldCoords` and `bWorldCoords` is set from the same value.